# Add +7days to current date?

Tags: php, date, addition, days

```
    $tmp['y'] = ($PDF->PageHeight*70.5)/100;
    $tmp['x']  = ($PDF->PageWidth*49.5)/100;
    $PDF->ShowTextAt($tmp['x'], $tmp['y'], date('m/d/Y'));
```

How would i add 7days to this current date code?

Answer (score 5):

[`strtotime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) is what I'd use.

```
echo date('m/d/Y', strtotime('+7 day'));
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php)

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime('2000-01-01');
$date->add(new DateInterval('P7D'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d') . "\n";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple example:

```php
$dt = new DateTime('+7 days');
echo $dt->format('Y-m-d');
```